# Number of triples $(a, b, c)$ with $1 \leq a,b,c \leq n$ which are coprime ($gcd(a,b,c)=1$)

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Number of ordered triples $(a, b, c)$ with $gcd(a, b, c) = 1$ and $1 \leq a, b, c \leq n$ can be computed using the following formula:
$$
C(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n\mu(k) \left \lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right \rfloor^3
$$,
where $\mu(n)$ is Moebius function.

But how it can be derived?

Thanks!

Comment: For the case $c=n$ see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689611/number-of-triplets-for-which-gcda-b-c-1-and-c-n). Similarly you can do the general case.