# In how many ways can $2^5\times 3^7$ be factored into three setwise coprime integers?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, permutations, combinations

Let $T$ be the following set of ordered triples, $T=\{(a,b,c):a,b,c\in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Find the number of elements in $T$ such that $abc=2^5\times 3^7$ and $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$

**My Attempt**

If $a=2^x;b=3^y;c=2^z\times 3^t$ then $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$

So, $x$ has $6$ choices, $y$ has $8$ choices and $z,t$ has $6\times 8$ choices. So required number of triples will be

$=6\times 8\times(6\times 8)\times 3!=13824$

Is my answer correct

Comment: So $H.C.F.(a,b,c)$ is $\gcd(a, b,c)$, right?

Comment: Yes. H.C.F is same as gcd

Comment: How would you treat $(2^5,3^7,1)$ vs $(1,3^7,2^5)$?

Comment: How about also something like $(1,2\times 3,2^4\times 3^6)$?

Comment: Yes. I missed that

Comment: Even if we were to have loosened requirements... Your approach with "6 options for x... and 6 options for z*" is incorrect since it depends on what the value chosen for $x$ was which determines what the value for $z$ is.  You only multiply if the earlier decisions don't affect quantity of future choices in steps during applying multiplication principle (rule of product).  The number of triples *of the form you were talking about* specifically of the form $(a,b,c)$ with $a=2^x,b=3^y$ etc... would have been $6\times 8$.  No need for a second six or eight being multiplied here at all.

Comment: See also [this formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1014955/number-of-triples-a-b-c-with-1-leq-a-b-c-leq-n-which-are-coprime-gcd?noredirect=1), which counts the coprime triples with $a,b,c\le n=2^5\cdot 3^7$. Of course, these are too many triples. But you can take different $n$ here.

Comment: As a start, can you think of a way to compute the number without the restriction on $HCF(a,b,c)$, just with the restriction $abc = 2^5 \cdot 3^7$?

Comment: I read *mutually coprime* as pairwise coprime.  A better term might be [*setwise coprime*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers#Coprimality_in_sets).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break into cases:

- Only one of $a,b,c$ has a factor of $2$
- Two of $a,b,c$ have factors of $2$

Note that it is impossible for all three to have a factor of $2$ since that would make their $\gcd$ at least $2$ and not $1$.

---

First case: Only one of $a,b,c$ has a factor of $2$.  Choose which it is.  Since this is the only one with a factor of $2$ it must have all of the factors of $2$ and so is of the form $2^5\times 3^x$ with the remaining two as $3^y,3^z$ such that $x+y+z=7$ and at least one of $x,y,z$ are zero (*else the gcd would have been at least $3$*)

Do the same, pick if it was only one number getting any factors of $3$ or two.  If one, pick which it was and it gets all of the factors.  If two, pick which gets the higher amount and which gets the lower amount, and how much the higher amount gets (*be it 4,5 or 6*).

This gives a total of $3\times (3 + 3\times 2\times 3) = 63$ in this case

---

Second case: Two of $a,b,c$ have factors of $2$.  Notice that $5$ is odd, so it is impossible for both to get the same amount of factors of $2$ simultaneously.  Pick which of $a,b,c$ gets the most factors of $2$.  Then pick which gets the least.  Pick whether the one that got the most got $4$ factors of $2$ or if it got $3$.

Our numbers are then $2^43^x, 2^13^y,3^z$ or $2^33^x,2^23^y,3^z$ in some order.

Next, let us distribute the $3$'s.  We do so in the same way as before.

$3\times 2\times 2\times (3 + 3\times 2\times 3) = 252$ in this case

---

This brings our combined total to $63+252 = 315$

Answer (score 2):

It appears that there is a direct method inspired by JMoravitz

Let $a=2^{x_1}3^{y_1};b=2^{x_2}3^{y_2};2^{x_3}3^{y_3}$

Here we must have $x_1+x_2+x_3=5$ such that at least one of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ is $0$ and we also must have $y_1+y_2+y_3=7$ such that at least one of $y_1,y_2,y_3$ is $0$

If exactly one of $x_i$ be $0$ then if $x_1=0$ and $x_2+x_3=5$. This can happen in $4$ ways. Thus if $x_2=0$ and $x_3=0$ then we have $3\times 4=12$ ways.

If exactly two of $x_i$ be $0$ then we have $3$ cases.

So, in all we have $12+3=15$ways.

By similar calculation for $y_i's$ we have $18+3=21$ ways.

So required number of triplets=$15\times 21=315$ ways

Answer (score 0):

My original answer was made for a duplicate and was similar to Maverick's answer here, so to have some added value here is a solution for slightly generalized case.

Let $T=\{(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n):a_i\in \mathbb{N}\}$, we want to find number of elements in $T$ such that $a_1a_2\cdots a_n=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$ for some distinct primes $p_i$.

First of all, we can solve the problem for each prime power separately, and then count all solutions by multiplying the values. We will use that number of non-negative integer tuples $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ such that $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n=m$ is $\binom{m+n-1}{n-1}$ (can be proven for example by [stars and bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))).

So let $a_1a_2\cdots a_n=p^{e}$, then $a_j=p^{f_j}$ such that $f_1+f_2+\dots+f_n=e$ and $f_j \geq 0$. Since we want $a_i$ to be (setwise) coprime, at least one of $a_j$ must not be divisible by $p$, hence at least one of $f_j=0$. We can count these by counting solutions where all $f_j \geq 0$ minus solutions where $f_j \geq 1$. The latter can be converted by subtracting one from each variable into $f_1'+\dots +f_n'=e-n$ with $f_j' \geq 0$. So overall for this prime power we get
$$
\binom{e+n-1}{n-1}-\binom{(e-n)+n-1}{n-1}.
$$
So product over all prime powers gives the final answer:
$$
\prod_{i=1}^k\left[ \binom{e_i+n-1}{n-1}-\binom{e_i-1}{n-1}\right].
$$

Applying to this particular problem we have $n=3$ and $(e_1,e_2)=(5,7)$, thus we get

$$
\left[ \binom{5+2}{2}-\binom{5-1}{2}\right]\cdot \left[ \binom{7+2}{2}-\binom{7-1}{2}\right]=315.
$$